# Replacing value before space?

Tags: c#, string

I want to replace only the value before space

for example:

```
1. 1 3
2. 23 5
3. 650 300
4. 1350 19
```

would be:

```
1. 2 3
2. 55 5
3. 950 300
4. 5602 19
```

I only need to change the value before space... after space should remain same. Every value is in a separate row. Before space value can be 1 to 4 digits and after space value can be 1 to 3 digits.

```cs
string num = "650 3";
                   
string afterspace = num.Substring(0, 4);
Console.WriteLine(afterspace);
                           
string beforespace = num.Substring(4);
Console.WriteLine(beforespace);
```

Comment: Please post your attempted code.

Comment: did you try any code to do this, please share here.

Comment: sorry @SulabhAgarwal I was trying substring but my values are in numbers as I am getting value from excel file substring was not a good approach that's why I didn't add code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a space separated string, you can try the bewlo approach..

```
var arr = str.Split(' ');

arr[0] = newValue;//here you can use the index and new value to assign the new value.

str = string.Join(" ",arr);
```